# Can't find draw all edges

Tags: interface, 3d-view, draw-mode

How do I enable draw all edges?  I researched a lot on google and all I got was go to display and check it. However it's not there!

[Here is an example](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/draw-all-edges.php) of what they told me.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's in *Properties > Object > Display:*

[image]

Note that this option is only available on mesh objects.

Comment: Facepalm... I was looking at the wrong display

Comment: do I have to do this for every object individually?

Comment: @Zachooz No, with all the objects selected, enable it, then right click on it and select `Copy to selected`.